# Counting created class objects

Tags: c++, oop

The issue does not need any explanations, I guess. I really don't know what I do wrong. I've made it once before and it was working properly. I'm still beginner in oop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Employee
{
private:
    static int counter;
public:
    Employee::Employee()
    {
        counter++;
    }

    Employee::~Employee()
    {
        counter--;
    }

    static int ShowCounter()
    {
        //std::cout << counter << std::endl;
        return counter;
    }
};

int Employee::counter = 0;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Employee> employees;

    std::cout << "Constructors: " << std::endl;
    employees.push_back(Employee());
    std::cout << Employee::ShowCounter() << std::endl;
    employees.push_back(Employee());
    std::cout << Employee::ShowCounter() << std::endl;
    employees.push_back(Employee());
    std::cout << Employee::ShowCounter() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Destructors: " << std::endl;
    employees.pop_back();
    std::cout << Employee::ShowCounter() << std::endl;
    employees.pop_back();
    std::cout << Employee::ShowCounter() << std::endl;
    employees.pop_back();
    std::cout << Employee::ShowCounter() << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

The output:

```
Constructors:
0
-1
-3
Destructors:
-4
-5
-6
```

I probably made some stupid mistake

EDIT: I afraid that it is against the rules but I have the next issue related with previous one. I've pasted minimal code which had to show my problem. Now, when I try to implement your solution into my main code I get the error `'Employee &Employee::operator =(const Employee &)': attempting to reference a deleted function'`. The line with issue:

```
employees[employees.size() - 1] = generate_random_employee(employees[employees.size() - 1], employees);
```

The function `generate_random_employee` is `Employee` type function. If u need more details I will ask a new question.

Comment: You don't count instances created from copy constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add:

```
Employee(const Employee&)
{
    counter++;
}
Employee( Employee&&)
{
    counter++;
}
```

and it should be fine

Comment: Unfortunately the solution does not work. Or I don't know how to use it. Now I'm gettng `Error: no instance of constructor "Employee:Employee" matches the argument list`

Comment: @mathsicist `Employee:Employee` is certainly wrong, you need `::`, see here: https://ideone.com/17TnWN

Comment: ok, I've got it. Thank you. Could u look at edited question?

Comment: You need to write explicitly assign operator, operator=.

Comment: Do u mean operator overloading?

Comment: Yes, move constructor caused implicit assignment operator to be deleted

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to count instances created with the default compiler generated copy/move constructor. If you create a user defined version, the counting should be balanced:

```
Employee::Employee(Employee&& rhs) // : Whatever needs to be copied/moved
{
    counter++;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/224fcac3bfc30ff2)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to handle copies.  Every time you push an element into the vector a copy is made.  So

```
employees.push_back(Employee());
```

Calls the constructor, makes a copy and then `Employee()` gets destroyed which leaves you with a net of 0.  unfortunately most empty vectors start at 0 capacity so the second call to `push_back` is going to need to grow the array.  When it does that you have one copy and one destruction.  This is my you see `-1` after the next insertion.  Then we grow the vector again so now we have 2 copies and 2 destructor calls so we go from -1 to -3.  Then when you empty the vector you have one destructor call for each element and since we have 3 elements we go from -3 to -6.  If we add a copy constructor like

```
Employee(const Employee& rhs)
{
    counter++;
}
```

Then we offset all of the destruction from the copies([Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c06e494af2e0afb)).

Comment: Ok, I understand now how it works. The questions is why `const Employee& rhs`. What does it mean? Maybe some link?

Comment: @mathsicist It is how you define a [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Comment: I'd like to make sure: all of what you've described is about how the `v.push_back(T())` works, is not? If will I use another container or just create a new object by `T obj` it would work fine without creating any copies? Am I thinking right?

Comment: @mathsicist unless you are using C++11 and your class is moveable then anytime you call `push_back` it will make a copy